# Porting application defined MBeans from OC4J

Tags: weblogic, spring-jmx

Applications that use Spring JMX deployed on OC4J have their "Application Defined MBeans" visible through Enterprise Manager.  When these applications are ported to Weblogic 12c, can these MBeans be made visible in the Weblogic console, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24416/accesscust.htm#JMXPG165 Particularly extending the console to view MBeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty good summary [here](http://captechconsulting.com/blog/ron-difrango/exposing-jmx-beans-weblogic-using-spring).  Like the author of that blog, I am using the WLST solution rather than attempting to extend the Weblogic console.

To that I would add:

- I didn't find it necessary to set -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
- I did have to set the property **name="registrationBehaviorName" value="REGISTRATION_IGNORE_EXISTING"** in my MBean exporter otherwise an InstanceAlreadyExistsException was thrown out of an interceptor when I exercised the app